# Reorder SymPy Expression

Tags: python, expression, sympy

I have a SymPy expression of the form `-x + y` (where x, y are atoms, not other expressions), but I would like to rearrange them so that they will be `y - x`, so basically just get rid of the spare `+` to get the expression shorter.
How can I (if it's possible) do that?

Example input and output:

```py
from sympy import *

expression = -4 + 2*I
reorder(expression) # how can I do that?
print(expression) # expected output: 2*I - 4
```

### Edit:

In case someone needs it, here is a solution for this problem, which can also accept expressions which are not of type `sympy.Add` and replace only the additions within them with the reordered additions, and eventually return the final latex:

```py
def negcolast(expr):
    from sympy.core.function import _coeff_isneg as neg
    if isinstance(expr, sympy.Add) and neg(expr.args[0]):
        args = list(expr.args)
        args.append(args.pop(0))
        return sympy.UnevaluatedExpr(sympy.Add(*args,evaluate=False))
    else:
        return expr

def latex(expr):
    expr = expr.replace(sympy.Add, lambda *args: negcolast(sympy.Add(*args)))
    return sympy.latex(expr, order='none')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a printing issue. No matter what order you put the args, they will be printed the same way. This comes up periodically and I have answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45679468/1089161) and especially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58541713/1089161). So if you have two args you need to find out if only one of them has a negative sign (e.g. using `sympy.core.function._coeff_isneg`), create an unevaluated Add (`Add(pos, neg, evaulate=False)`) and then print that with the printer after telling it not to re-order terms.

```
>>> def negcolast(expr):
...     from sympy.core.function import _coeff_isneg as neg
...     if isinstance(expr, Add) and neg(expr.args[0]):
...         args = list(expr.args)
...         args.append(args.pop(0))
...         return LatexPrinter({'order':'none'})._print_Add(Add(*args,evaluate=False))
...     else:
...         return latex(expr)
... 
>>> negcolast(-4+2*I)
2i−4
```

Comment: Do you have a simple idea how to implement it into the `sympy.latex` function at least?

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: I had an equation that is like x-1 and in the above code, it was outputting it as -1+x so I suggest you to change the last line to `return latex(expr, order='none')`. That fixed my issue.