# Numerical Integration over a Matrix of Functions, SymPy and SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, symbolic-math, numerical-integration

From my SymPy output I have the matrix shown below, which I must integrate in 2D. Currently I am doing it element-wise as shown below. This method works but it gets too slow (for both `sympy.mpmath.quad` and `scipy.integrate.dblquad`) for my real case (in which `A` and its functions are much bigger (see edit below):

```
from sympy import Matrix, sin, cos
import sympy
import scipy
sympy.var( 'x, t' )
A = Matrix([[(sin(2-0.1*x)*sin(t)*x+cos(2-0.1*x)*cos(t)*x)*cos(3-0.1*x)*cos(t)],
            [(cos(2-0.1*x)*sin(t)*x+sin(2-0.1*x)*cos(t)*x)*sin(3-0.1*x)*cos(t)],
            [(cos(2-0.1*x)*sin(t)*x+cos(2-0.1*x)*sin(t)*x)*sin(3-0.1*x)*sin(t)]])

# integration intervals
x1,x2,t1,t2 = (30, 75, 0, 2*scipy.pi)

# element-wise integration
from sympy.utilities import lambdify
from sympy.mpmath import quad
from scipy.integrate import dblquad
A_int1 = scipy.zeros( A.shape, dtype=float )
A_int2 = scipy.zeros( A.shape, dtype=float )
for (i,j), expr in scipy.ndenumerate(A):
    tmp = lambdify( (x,t), expr, 'math' )
    A_int1[i,j] = quad( tmp, (x1, x2), (t1, t2) )
    # or (in scipy)
    A_int2[i,j] = dblquad( tmp, t1, t2, lambda x:x1, lambda x:x2 )[0]
```

I was considering doing it in one shot like, but I'm not sure if this is the way to go:

```
A_eval = lambdify( (x,t), A, 'math' )
A_int1 = sympy.quad( A_eval, (x1, x2), (t1, t2)                 
# or (in scipy)
A_int2 = scipy.integrate.dblquad( A_eval, t1, t2, lambda x: x1, lambda x: x2 )[0]
```

---

EDIT:
The real case has been made available in [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eyh4zr8ee9lgq84/numerical-integration-over-a-matrix-of-functions-sympy-and-scipy.zip). Just unzip and run `shadmehri_2012.py` (is the author from were this example was taken from: [Shadmehri et al. 2012](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263822311003606)).
I've started a bounty of 50 for the one who can do the following:

- make it reasonably faster than the proposed question
- manage to run without giving memory error even with a number of terms `m=15` and `n=15` in the code), I managed up to `m=7` and `n=7` in 32-bit

The current timing can be summarized below(measured with m=3 and n=3). From there it can be seen that the numerical integration is the bottleneck.

build trial functions             =  0%
evaluating differential equations =  2%
lambdifying k1                    = 22%
integrating k1                    = 74%
lambdifying and integrating k2    =  2%
extracting eigenvalues            =  0%

---

Related questions: [about lambdify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10683911/832621)

Comment: And profiling your code with `line_profiler` http://silas.sewell.org/blog/2009/05/28/python-line-by-line-profiler-line_profiler-and-kernprof/ would have helped you.

Comment: The problem is that A is obtained after applying an automatic differentiation over another matrix, using the procedure described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16237073/832621), explaining why it comes from SymPy. I fully agree with you to use directly the numeric modules like `numpy` when applicable.

Comment: Oh, my bad... And looking closely at the code it seems my issue nb. 1 is also incorrect, as you are not redoing the `lambdify` call each time. So in the hope of actually being helpful unlike in the previous comment: have you actually tried to do the integration symbolically with numpy. If it is only `sin`, `cos` and polynomials it should be easy. Especially if you can permit yourself to rewrite it as exponentials `expr.rewrite(exp).expand()` (there are complex numbers popping out, but after evaluation it is real).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try the symbolic integration with `sympy` (I guess it is `sympy` what you meant, isn't it?) before going further, this would really save time...

Comment: Indeed, I mean `sympy`. I must still be sleepy :) ...

Comment: Two more tips if you go that route: 1. Call `trigsimp` (or just `simplify`) on the expression first. 2. Use the git master of `sympy`. There have been a lot of improvements to trigsimp and integration since the last official release.

Comment: actually @Krastanov puts off the slowest integration algorithms to the very end.

Comment: I have removed a wrong comment pointed out by @asmeurer. To correct myself: the symbolic integration routine tries various integration algorithms starting with fast-but-not-general and ending with slow-but-more-general. If you know that the less general ones do not work you can skip them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can avoid the lambdification time by switching to numerical evaluation at a different stage of the calculation.

Namely, your calculation seems to be diagonal in the sense that `k1` and `k2` are both of the form `k = g^T X g` where X is some 5x5 matrix (with differential ops inside, but that doesn't matter), and `g` is 5xM, with M large. Therefore `k[i,j] = g.T[i,:] * X * g[:,j]`.

So you can just replace

```
for j in xrange(1,n+1):
    for i in xrange(1,m+1):
        g1 += [uu(i,j,x,t),          0,          0,          0,          0]
        g2 += [          0,vv(i,j,x,t),          0,          0,          0]
        g3 += [          0,          0,ww(i,j,x,t),          0,          0]
        g4 += [          0,          0,          0,bx(i,j,x,t),          0]
        g5 += [          0,          0,          0,          0,bt(i,j,x,t)]
g = Matrix( [g1, g2, g3, g4, g5] )
```

with

```
i1 = Symbol('i1')
j1 = Symbol('j1')
g1 = [uu(i1,j1,x,t),          0,          0,          0,          0]
g2 = [          0,vv(i1,j1,x,t),          0,          0,          0]
g3 = [          0,          0,ww(i1,j1,x,t),          0,          0]
g4 = [          0,          0,          0,bx(i1,j1,x,t),          0]
g5 = [          0,          0,          0,          0,bt(i1,j1,x,t)]
g_right = Matrix( [g1, g2, g3, g4, g5] )

i2 = Symbol('i2')
j2 = Symbol('j2')
g1 = [uu(i2,j2,x,t),          0,          0,          0,          0]
g2 = [          0,vv(i2,j2,x,t),          0,          0,          0]
g3 = [          0,          0,ww(i2,j2,x,t),          0,          0]
g4 = [          0,          0,          0,bx(i2,j2,x,t),          0]
g5 = [          0,          0,          0,          0,bt(i2,j2,x,t)]
g_left = Matrix( [g1, g2, g3, g4, g5] )
```

and

```
tmp = evaluateExpr( B*g )
k1 = r*tmp.transpose() * F * tmp
k2 = r*g.transpose()*evaluateExpr(Bc*g)
k2 = evaluateExpr( k2 )
```

by

```
tmp_right = evaluateExpr( B*g_right )
tmp_left = evaluateExpr( B*g_left )
k1 = r*tmp_left.transpose() * F * tmp_right
k2 = r*g_left.transpose()*evaluateExpr(Bc*g_right)
k2 = evaluateExpr( k2 )
```

Didn't test (past am), but you get the idea.

Now, instead of having a huge symbolic matrix which makes everything slow, you have two matrix indices for the trial function indices, and free parameters `i1,j1` and `i2,j2` which play their role and you should substitute integers into them in the end.

Since the matrix to lambdify is only 5x5, and needs to be lambdified only once outside all loops, the lambdification and simplification overhead is gone. Moreover, the problem fits easily into memory even for large m, n.

The integration is not any faster, but since the expressions are very small, you can easily e.g. [dump them in Fortran](https://gist.github.com/pv/5506308) or do something else smart.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunately the problem is not diagonalizable... when doing `B*g` the result is a quite dense matrix. Also, I need all the extension of `g` since the final matrix for eigenvalue analysis is a `cXc` matrix, with `c=5*m*n`, and I need like this to calculate the Ritz coefficients...

Comment: Yes, but keeping `i1,j1,i2,j2` as symbolic indices, you do not need to construct the full symbolic matrix before lambdification, which is the point of my answer. You can evaluate the final `cxc` matrix by substituting integers to lambdified expression.

Comment: why did you use a `g_left` and `g_right ` if they are the same?

Comment: They are not the same: if you use the same `i,j` in them, you can only generate the diagonal blocks of the final `g^T X g` matrix.

Comment: it would be nice if you could detail even more your answer. I still did not get the point about how to use `i1,j1,i2,j2`. I've updated [the original code here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eyh4zr8ee9lgq84/numerical-integration-over-a-matrix-of-functions-sympy-and-scipy.zip) in case you want to take a look...

Comment: maybe I got your point...calling `B^T*F*B=A` at the end we have `[g_left11, g_left21, g_left12, g_left22]^T*A*[g_right11, g_right21, g_right12, g_right22]`, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

[quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (a project of mine) does *vectorized* numerical integration. This

```
from numpy import sin, cos, pi
import quadpy


def f(X):
    x, t = X
    return [
        [(sin(2-0.1*x)*sin(t)*x+cos(2-0.1*x)*cos(t)*x)*cos(3-0.1*x)*cos(t)],
        [(cos(2-0.1*x)*sin(t)*x+sin(2-0.1*x)*cos(t)*x)*sin(3-0.1*x)*cos(t)],
        [(cos(2-0.1*x)*sin(t)*x+cos(2-0.1*x)*sin(t)*x)*sin(3-0.1*x)*sin(t)]
        ]


x1 = 30
x2 = 75
t1 = 0
t2 = 2*pi

sol = quadpy.quadrilateral.integrate(
        f,
        [[x1, t1], [x2, t1], [x2, t2], [x1, t2]],
        quadpy.quadrilateral.Product(quadpy.line_segment.GaussLegendre(5))
        )

print(sol)
```

gives

```
[[ 1456.3701526 ]
 [ 2620.60490653]
 [ 5034.5831071 ]]
```

Timings:

```
%timeit quadpy.quadrilateral.integrate(f, [[x1, t1], [x2, t1], [x2, t2], [x1, t2]], q)
1000 loops, best of 3: 219 µs per loop
```

This leads to dramatic speedup in your downloadable example:

```
import numpy
array2mat = [{'ImmutableMatrix': numpy.array}, 'numpy']
k1_lambda = lambdify( (x,t), k1, modules=array2mat)
print 'Finished lambdifying k1:', time.clock()
import quadpy
sol = quadpy.quadrilateral.integrate(
    lambda X: k1_lambda(X[0], X[1]),
    [[x1, t1], [x2, t1], [x2, t2], [x1, t2]],
    quadpy.quadrilateral.Product(quadpy.line_segment.GaussLegendre(5))
    )
```

Output:

```
Start: 0.040001
Finished trial functions: 0.379929
Finished evaluating differential equations: 2.669536
Finished lambdifying k1: 29.961808
Finished integrating k1: 30.106988
Finished lambdifying and integrating k2: 34.229007
Finished calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors: 34.229924
```

Note that *quadpy* doesn't do adaptive quadrature, so choose your scheme wisely.