# Integration of big trigonometric functions

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

In SymPy, what is the recommended way to integrate a big trigonometric functions like this one shown below? The numerical integration gives `-27151.225`.

```
from sympy import pi, sin, cos
from sympy.abc import x, t
function = 1.55572382686041*(1.5263628489853e-9*x**(-1)*sin(10.9175359259421*pi -0.0301592300440543*pi*x)*sin(t)*x - 17456139.8613791*x**(-1)*sin(10.9175359259421*pi - 0.0301592300440543*pi*x)*cos(t)*x + 9401.13817429496*pi*cos(10.9175359259421*pi - 0.0301592300440543*pi*x)*cos(t)*x)*x**(-1)*cos(32.7526077778264*pi - 0.0904776901321629*pi*x)*cos(t) + (1162050.0*x**(-1)*sin(10.9175359259421*pi - 0.0301592300440543*pi*x)*sin(t)*x - 9.81127127213595e-10*x**(-1)*sin(10.9175359259421*pi - 0.0301592300440543*pi*x)*cos(t)*x + 3.43953078983083e-13*pi*cos(10.9175359259421*pi - 0.0301592300440543*pi*x)*cos(t)*x)*(-1.0*x**(-1)*cos(32.7526077778264*pi - 0.0904776901321629*pi*x)*sin(t) + 0.0904776901321629*pi*sin(32.7526077778264*pi - 0.0904776901321629*pi*x)*sin(t))
function.integrate( (x,362.,395.154), (t,0,2*pi) )
```

This type of function is generated in the problem [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295140/numerical-integration-over-a-matrix-of-functions-sympy-and-scipy).

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=3152.