# sympy subs not working correctly after using a custom differential operator

Tags: python, sympy

I have defined a custom differential operator taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16237073/21205111) in a file named differential_operator.py

I am using this operator to calculate the strain in a shell finite element (solid mechanics) problem (file name: sym_calc.py).

```
import differential_operator as do
import sympy as sp

numNodeElem = 2
numNodeDOF = 5

fieldVars = ['u', 'v', 'w', 'phi', 'psi']
xi, theta, z = sp.symbols(['xi', 'theta', 'z'], commutative=False)
J, alpha, n, s = sp.symbols(['J', 'alpha', 'n', 's'], commutative=False)

LO = sp.Matrix([[1 / J * do.D(xi), 0, 0, z / J * do.D(xi), 0], 
                [1 / s, 1 / s / sp.sin(alpha) * do.D(theta), 1 / s / sp.tan(alpha), z / s, z / s / sp.sin(alpha) * do.D(theta)], 
                [1 / s / sp.sin(alpha) * do.D(theta), 1 / J * do.D(xi) - 1 / s, 0, z / s / sp.sin(alpha) * do.D(theta), z * (1 / J * do.D(xi) - 1 / s)], 
                [0, 0, 1 / J * do.D(xi), 1, 0], 
                [0, - 1 / s / sp.tan(alpha), 1 / s / sp.sin(alpha) * do.D(theta), 0, 1]])

if numNodeElem == 2 :
    N_i = sp.Matrix([0.5*(1 - xi), 0.5*(1 + xi)])
elif numNodeElem == 3:
    N_i = sp.Matrix([0.5*(xi**2- xi), (1 - xi**2), 0.5*(xi**2 + xi)])

N = sp.zeros(numNodeDOF, numNodeElem*numNodeDOF)
for i in range(numNodeDOF) :
    for index, j in enumerate(range(0, numNodeElem*numNodeDOF, numNodeDOF)) :
        if i == 0 or i==2 or i==3 :
            N[i, j + i] = N_i[index] * sp.cos(n * theta)
        else :
            N[i, j + i] = N_i[index] * sp.sin(n * theta)

deltaApprox = sp.zeros(numNodeElem * numNodeDOF, 1)
for thisNode in range(numNodeElem) :
    for index, thisFieldVar in enumerate(fieldVars) :
        deltaApprox[thisNode * numNodeDOF + index] = sp.Symbol(fieldVars[index] + str(thisNode + 1), commutative=False)

delta = N * deltaApprox

sApprox = sp.Integer(0)
for thisNode in range(numNodeElem) :
    sApprox = sApprox + sp.Symbol('s' + str(thisNode + 1), commutative=False) * N_i[thisNode]


## test1 : correctly substituted
tempLO = LO.subs(s, sApprox)
strain1 = tempLO*delta
strain1 = do.evaluateExpr(strain1)
print('strain1', strain1)

## test2 : not substituted
strain2 = LO*delta
strain2 = do.evaluateExpr(strain2)
strain2 = strain2.subs(s, sApprox)
print('strain2', strain2)

## test3 : not substituted
strain3 = LO*delta
strain3 = do.evaluateExpr(strain3)
strain3 = strain3.subs({sp.Dummy(s.name): sApprox})
print('strain3', strain3)
```

In `test1`, if I substitute the `sApprox` before evaluating the operator, I have the correct substitution, but in `test2` and `test3`, the `s` in the `strain` is not substituted by `sApprox` at all.

I want to know how to `subs` correctly in `test2` and `test3`. I need it to do further substitutions and integration of the terms.