# sympy: 'Transpose' object has no attribute tolist

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm trying to do some symbolic matrix calculations with sympy. My goal is to obtain a symbolic representation of the result of some matrix computations. I've run into some problems which I have boiled down to this simple example, in which I try to evaluate the result of a exponentiating a specified matrix and multiplying it by an arbitrary vector.

```
>>> import sympy
>>> v = sympy.MatrixSymbol('v', 2, 1)
>>> Z = sympy.zeros(2, 2)  # create 2x2 zero matrix
>>> I = sympy.exp(Z)  # exponentiate zero matrix to get identity matrix
>>> I * v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 507, in __mul__
    blst = B.T.tolist()
AttributeError: 'Transpose' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

In contrast, if I directly create the identity matrix and then multiply it by v, then there is no problem:

```
>>> I_ = sympy.eye(2)  # directly create the identity matrix
>>> I_ == I  # check the two matrices are equal
True
>>> I_ * v
v
```

One thing that I've noted is that the two identity matrices are of different classes:

```
>>> I.__class__
sympy.matrices.immutable.ImmutableMatrix
>>> I_.__class__
sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix
```

I also found that calling the `as_mutable()` method provided a work-around.

```
>>> I.as_mutable() * v
v
```

Is it always necessary to put `as_mutable()` calls throughout one's linear algebra calculations? I'm guessing not, and that instead these errors suggest that I'm using the wrong strategy to solve my problem, but I can't figure out what the right strategy would be. Does anyone have any pointers?

I have read the documentation page on [Immutable Matrices](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/matrices/immutablematrices.html) but I could still use some help understanding how their differences with standard mutable matrices are important here, and why some operations (e.g. sympy.exp) convert between these different classes.

Comment: FYI, the bug is fixed in sympy's master branch now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd claim that this is a bug in Sympy:

In Python, you can [overload the multiplication operator from both sides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5182501/1881610). `A*B` may internally be handled by either calling `A.__mul__(B)`, or `B.__rmul__(A)`. Python first calls `A.__mul__`, and if this method does not exist or returns `NotImplemented`,  then Python tries `B.__rmul__` automatically. SymPy instead uses a decorator called [call_highest_priority](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/decorators.py) to decide which of both implementations to use. It looks up the `_op_priority` of the involved classes and calls the function of the implementation with higher priority.  The priorities in your case are 11 for `v` and `I` and 10.01 for `I_`, so `I` is preferred. Also, the base implementation of `__mul__`, which `I` uses, lacks the decorator.

Long story short, `I*v` ends up always calling `I.__mul__`, and `__mul__` cannot handle `MatrixSymbol`s but does not return `NotImplemented` either. `v.__rmul__(I)` works as expected.

The proper fix would be to capture the `AttributeError` in `matrices.py` and return `NotImplemented`, i.e.

```
try:
    blst = B.T.tolist()
except AttributeError:
    return NotImplemented
```

Python would then automatically fallback to `__rmul__`. The hack'ish fix would be to adjust `_op_priority`. Either way, you should file a bug report: If the error was by design (that is, if you accidentally tried something that's not supposed to work), then the error message would say so.