# Changing the order of operation for __add__, __mul__, etc. methods in a custom class

Tags: python, class, object, operator-overloading

I have a vector class:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    def __str__(self):
        return '(%s,%s)' % (self.x, self.y)
    def __add__(self, n):
        if isinstance(n, (int, long, float)):
            return Vector(self.x+n, self.y+n)
        elif isinstance(n, Vector):
            return Vector(self.x+n.x, self.y+n.y)
```

which works fine, i.e. I can write:

```
a = Vector(1,2)
print(a + 1) # prints (2,3)
```

However if the order of operation is reversed, then it fails:

```
a = Vector(1,2)
print(1 + a) # raises TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)
             #                   for +: 'int' and 'instance'
```

I understand the error: the addition of an `int` object to an `Vector` object is undefined because I haven't defined it in the `int` class. Is there a way to work around this without defining it in the `int` (or parent of `int`) class?

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names). Also see [A Guide to Python's Magic Methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) by Rafe Kettler, and [Python’s magic methods](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/pythons-magic-methods)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to also define `__radd__`

Some operations do not necessarily evaluate like this a + b == b + a and that's why Python defines the **add** and **radd** methods.

Explaining myself better: it supports the fact that "int" does not define a `+` operation with `class Vector` instances as part of the operation. Therefore vector + 1 is not the same as 1 + vector.

When Python tries to see what the `1.__add__` method can do, an exception is raised. And Python goes and looks for `Vector.__radd__` operation to try to complete it.

In the OP's case the evaluation is **true** and suffices with `__radd__ = __add__`

```
class Vector(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%s,%s)' % (self.x, self.y)

    def __add__(self, n):
        if isinstance(n, (int, long, float)):
            return Vector(self.x+n, self.y+n)
        elif isinstance(n, Vector):
            return Vector(self.x+n.x, self.y+n.y)

    __radd__ = __add__


a = Vector(1, 2)
print(1 + a)
```

Which outputs:

```
(2,3)
```

The same applies to all number-like operations.

Comment: Maybe some more explanation is needed here?

Comment: is it similar for `__mul__`, `__div__`, etc? so `__rmul__`, `__rdiv__`, etc?

Comment: Yes if the first object in the operation (everything is an object) does not support the operation with the 2nd object

Comment: good answer, I'm accepting this answer mainly because of the hint `__radd__=__add__`, i like one-line solutions :)

Comment: In your case it is the solution ;)

Comment: I also liked this hint, removes unnecessary additional work with implementing the `__radd__`

Answer (score 4):

When you say `x + y`, Python calls `x.__add__(y)`. If x does not implement `__add__` (or that method returns `NotImplemented`), Python tries to call `y.__radd__(x)` as a fallback.

Thus all you have to do is to define the `__radd__()` method in your Vector class and `1 + y` will work as you would expect.

Note: you would have to do similar for other operations too, e.g. implement `__mul__()` and `__rmul__()` pair, etc.

You might also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181320/under-what-circumstances-are-rmul-called), it explains the same principle in more details.

**Update:**
Depending on your use case, you might also want to implement the [`__iadd__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) method (and its cousins) to override the `+=` operator.

For example, if you say `y += 1` (`y` being an instance of `Vector` here), you might want to modify the `y` instance itself, and not return a new `Vector` instance as a result, which what your `__add__()` method currently does.