# Function called when using binary operators, python

Tags: python

I'm exploring python.

If have now lerned from the answers, that when I use `*`,

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a*2
c = 2*a
```

`a.__mul__()` is called to compute `b` and `a.__rmul__()` to compute `c` (and this is more expensive, since the integer is tried to be called first :))

**So, in general:**

How can I see which function is called for some shortcut operator like `*`, `and`, or `+=`, ...

Comment: This kind of multiplication is commutative, so it comes out to the same thing, so both are right.

Comment: aaah! does r mean reverse or right or something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181320/under-what-circumstances-are-rmul-called

Comment: Also http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python language reference 3.3.7: Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) says this of the `__rXXX__` magic methods:

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `//`, `%`, `divmod()`, `pow()`, `**`, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `^`, `|`) with ***r***eflected (swapped) operands. These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types. For instance, to evaluate the expression `x - y`, where `y` is an instance of a class that has an `__rsub__()` method, `y.__rsub__(x)` is called if `x.__sub__(y)` returns `NotImplemented`.

---

Thus for your case: at first for `a * b` Python tries to call `a.__mul__(b)`. If this method does not exist or returns `NotImplemented`, Python calls `b.__rmul__(a)`. If that returns a value that is not `NotImplemented`, that shall be the result of multiplication.

That way only one of `a` or `b` needs to support multiplication by the other.

---

In this specific case of multiplying a list (or any sequence) by an integer, it is slightly more efficient to do `[1, 2, 3] * 2` than `2 * [1, 2, 3]`; both give the same result, but `[1, 2, 3] * 2` calls `list.__mul__` first:

```
>>> [1,2,3].__mul__(2)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

The latter calls `int.__mul__` first, which, given a `list`, returns `NotImplemented`:

```
>>> (2).__mul__([1,2,3])
NotImplemented
```

Then Python proceeds to calling `[1, 2, 3].__rmul__(2)`:

```
>>> [1,2,3].__rmul__(2)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

---

And of course multiplication is **not** generally commutative; think about matrix multiplication

Comment: Tigerhawks links were faster, but thank you nonetheless! :) so the second part is left, how this is in general...

Comment: thanks for the edit, I had just thought of it myself, haha :)

Comment: The link answers my question, I have to confess :) ... but still it would be nice to be able to see this "from within", not by reading documentation, but e.g. by getting a list of all called methods. But probably this is not possible...?

Comment: This all happens in C code in CPython, so not really, except with a custom class

Comment: I see. But this means: if I would overwrite the `__mul__` method and add a `print` statement inside to see when it is executed, it would be much slower because I overwrite in python? 
But I don't see the connection. I heard of profiling, which should list all function calls? Would this not list these because they are built-in?
Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: A Python profiler can only see Python function calls. It does not see `*` calling `int.__mul__` or `list.__rmul__` because, well the C code is not even calling `int.__mul__` but `PyNumber_Multiply` which looks up some functions in `PyType`, all in C.

Comment: Okay, thank you, maybe I understand :) So eventually built-in types are treated different from custom user-defined classes. I have first to read the links carefully, probably...

Answer (score 1):

`__mul__` is called when the object itself is on the left, and `__rmul__` is for when it's on the right. For these particular objects, `2*a` has the same result as `a*2` because this kind of multiplication is commutative, so it comes out to the same thing, so both docstrings are right.

Comment: Yes, thank you, especially for the links, now I understand the 'r'. But it still doesn't explain, how I can figure this out, what is called. I will read through your second link first, this will take some time, and then I can maybe accept this :)

Comment: @Ilja - For the object on the left, `__mul__` is called. For the object on the right, `__rmul__` is called. For cases where it's not commutative, the two methods may be defined differently.

Comment: ah, no sorry, I understood that, of course. I meant about any other operators, different from '*'

Comment: You'll have to look in the documentation for that object/type to read about its defined behaviors.