# Overriding other __rmul__ with your class's __mul__

Tags: python, numpy

In Python, is it possible for your class's `__rmul__` method to override another class's `__mul__` method, without making changes to the other class?

This question arises since I'm writing a class for a certain type of linear operator, and I want it to be able to multiply numpy arrays using the multiplication syntax. Here is a minimal example illustrating the issue:

```
import numpy as np    

class AbstractMatrix(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return np.dot(self.data, other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return np.dot(other, self.data)
```

Left multiplication works fine:

```
In[11]: A = AbstractMatrix()
In[12]: B = np.array([[4, 5],[6, 7]])
In[13]: A*B
Out[13]: 
array([[16, 19],
       [36, 43]])
```

But right multiplication defaults to `np.ndarray`'s version, which splits the array up and performs multiplication element-by-element (this not what is desired):

```
In[14]: B*A
Out[14]: 
array([[array([[ 4,  8],
       [12, 16]]),
        array([[ 5, 10],
       [15, 20]])],
       [array([[ 6, 12],
       [18, 24]]),
        array([[ 7, 14],
       [21, 28]])]], dtype=object)
```

In this situation, how can I make it call my own class's `__rmul__` on the original (unsplit) array?

Answers addressing the specific case of numpy arrays are welcome but I am also interested in the general idea of overriding methods of another third party class that cannot be modified.

Comment: Why don't you use the `@` operator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5182501/2823755

Comment: I believe that the only circumstance when __rXXX__ methods get checked before the usual __XXX__ methods are when the right-side object is a subclass of the left-side object.  I don't know enough about numpy internals to know whether they even can be subclassed.

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__) - ```These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types```

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo: OP doesn't say what version is being targeted. `@` operator is _very_ new, [only added in 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-465-a-dedicated-infix-operator-for-matrix-multiplication).

Comment: @jasonnharper I thought it was when the left operand was a base type or a subclass of one, you might be right, or maybe we both are

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo As someone doing numerical analysis, the @ operator looks amazing! What a great decision by the python community. I'm using Python 2.7.6, but this alone might get me to go to 3.x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to make `NumPy` respect your `__rmul__` method is to set an [`__array_priority__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.class.__array_priority__):

```
class AbstractMatrix(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return np.dot(self.data, other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return np.dot(other, self.data)

    __array_priority__ = 10000

A = AbstractMatrix()
B = np.array([[4, 5],[6, 7]])
```

This works like expected.

```
>>> B*A
array([[19, 28],
       [27, 40]])
```

The problem is that `NumPy` doesn't respect [Pythons "Numeric" Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__). If a numpy array is the first argument and `numpy.ndarray.__mul__` isn't possible then it tries something like:

```
result = np.empty(B.shape, dtype=object)
for idx, item in np.ndenumerate(B):
    result[idx] = A.__rmul__(item)
```

However if the second argument has an `__array_priority__` and it's higher than the one of the first argument only then it **really** uses:

```
A.__rmul__(B)
```

---

However since Python 3.5 ([PEP-465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)) there is the `@` ([`__matmul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__matmul__)) operator that can utilize matrix multiplication:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
>>> B = np.array([[4, 5],[6, 7]])
>>> B @ A
array([[19, 28],
       [27, 40]])
```