# Python vs MATLAB performance on algorithm

Tags: python, matlab, performance, numpy, time-complexity

I have a performance question about two bits of code.  One is implemented in python and one in MATLAB.  The code calculates the sample entropy of a time series (which sounds complicated but is basically a bunch of for loops).

I am running both implementations on relatively large time series (~95k+ samples) depending on the time series.  The MATLAB implementation finishes the calculation in ~45 sec to 1 min. The python one basically never finishes.  I threw tqdm over the python for loops and the upper loop was only moving at about ~1.85s/it which gives 50+ hours as a estimated completion time (I've let it run for 15+ mins and the iteration count was pretty consistent).

Example inputs and runtimes:

MATLAB (~ 52 sec):

```
a = rand(1, 95000)
sampenc(a, 4, 0.1 * std(a))
```

Python (currently 5 mins in with 49 hours estimated):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(1, 95000)[0]
sample_entropy(a, 4, 0.1 * np.std(a))
```

Python Implementation:

```python
# https://github.com/nikdon/pyEntropy
def sample_entropy(time_series, sample_length, tolerance=None):
    """Calculate and return Sample Entropy of the given time series.
    Distance between two vectors defined as Euclidean distance and can
    be changed in future releases
    Args:
        time_series: Vector or string of the sample data
        sample_length: Number of sequential points of the time series
        tolerance: Tolerance (default = 0.1...0.2 * std(time_series))
    Returns:
        Vector containing Sample Entropy (float)
    References:
        [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_Entropy
        [2] http://physionet.incor.usp.br/physiotools/sampen/
        [3] Madalena Costa, Ary Goldberger, CK Peng. Multiscale entropy analysis
            of biological signals
    """
    if tolerance is None:
        tolerance = 0.1 * np.std(time_series)

    n = len(time_series)
    prev = np.zeros(n)
    curr = np.zeros(n)
    A = np.zeros((sample_length, 1))  # number of matches for m = [1,...,template_length - 1]
    B = np.zeros((sample_length, 1))  # number of matches for m = [1,...,template_length]

    for i in range(n - 1):
        nj = n - i - 1
        ts1 = time_series[i]
        for jj in range(nj):
            j = jj + i + 1
            if abs(time_series[j] - ts1) < tolerance:  # distance between two vectors
                curr[jj] = prev[jj] + 1
                temp_ts_length = min(sample_length, curr[jj])
                for m in range(int(temp_ts_length)):
                    A[m] += 1
                    if j < n - 1:
                        B[m] += 1
            else:
                curr[jj] = 0
        for j in range(nj):
            prev[j] = curr[j]

    N = n * (n - 1) / 2
    B = np.vstack(([N], B[:sample_length - 1]))
    similarity_ratio = A / B
    se = - np.log(similarity_ratio)
    se = np.reshape(se, -1)
    return se
```

MATLAB Implementation:

```matlab
function [e,A,B]=sampenc(y,M,r);
%function [e,A,B]=sampenc(y,M,r);
%
%Input
%
%y input data
%M maximum template length
%r matching tolerance
%
%Output
%
%e sample entropy estimates for m=0,1,...,M-1
%A number of matches for m=1,...,M
%B number of matches for m=0,...,M-1 excluding last point

n=length(y);
lastrun=zeros(1,n);
run=zeros(1,n);
A=zeros(M,1);
B=zeros(M,1);
p=zeros(M,1);
e=zeros(M,1);

for i=1:(n-1)
   nj=n-i;
   y1=y(i);
   for jj=1:nj
      j=jj+i;      
      if abs(y(j)-y1)<r
         run(jj)=lastrun(jj)+1;
         M1=min(M,run(jj));
         for m=1:M1           
            A(m)=A(m)+1;
            if j<n
               B(m)=B(m)+1;
            end            
         end
      else
         run(jj)=0;
      end      
   end
   for j=1:nj
      lastrun(j)=run(j);
   end
end
N=n*(n-1)/2;
B=[N;B(1:(M-1))];
p=A./B;
e=-log(p);
```

I've also tried a few other python implementations and all of them have the same slow result:
[vectorized-sample-entropy](https://github.com/kirajcg/vectorized-sample-entropy)

[sampen](https://pypi.org/project/sampen/)

[sampen2.py](https://github.com/bergantine/sampen/blob/develop/sampen/sampen2.py)

[Wikipedia sample entropy implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_entropy)

I don't think computer issue as it runs relativity fast in MATLAB.

As far as I can tell, implementation-wise both sets of code are the same.  I have no idea why the python implementations are so slow. I would understand a difference of a few seconds but not such a large discrepancy. Let me know your thoughts on why this is or suggestions on how to improve the python versions.

BTW: I'm using Python 3.6.5 with numpy 1.14.5 and MATLAB R2018a.

Comment: you don't seem to use the vectorized capabilities of numpy, list slicing etc... try to reduce the python loops.

Comment: You seem to have a quadratic and perhaps even cubic algorithm. AFAIK, later versions of MATLAB know how to compile code, not just interpret it. So even hand rolled for-loops will be fast-ish. You're also using a lot of vectorized operations, which are going to be really fast. There's none of that in Python. The language is interpreted without anything fancy like JITs etc. Also, you're not using any lower-level vector library, but rather doing everything in Python. Performance is going to suffer. Though I have to admit the difference is quite large .. might be worth looking for a bug.

Comment: A while back I discussed a similar MATLAB vs numpy comparison on Code Review, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17702/python-numpy-running-15x-slower-than-matlab-am-i-using-numpy-effeciently.  Speeding up numpy code by replacing the loops with 'whole-array' operations (as required by older MATLAB versions) is a frequent SO topic.

Comment: Matlab has by default a jit compiler, Python not. You can use Numba to jit complie your code. This often outperforms the Matlab jit compiler eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50890174/4045774

Comment: I guess you are running this on many time series. Is the sample length the same for all series? Since this is embarrassingly parallel, parallelization would be the next step.

Answer (score 4):

As said in the comments, Matlab uses a jit-compiler by default Python doesn't. In Python you could use Numba to do quite the same.

**Your code with slight modifications**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import time

@nb.jit(fastmath=True,error_model='numpy')
def sample_entropy(time_series, sample_length, tolerance=None):
    """Calculate and return Sample Entropy of the given time series.
    Distance between two vectors defined as Euclidean distance and can
    be changed in future releases
    Args:
        time_series: Vector or string of the sample data
        sample_length: Number of sequential points of the time series
        tolerance: Tolerance (default = 0.1...0.2 * std(time_series))
    Returns:
        Vector containing Sample Entropy (float)
    References:
        [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_Entropy
        [2] http://physionet.incor.usp.br/physiotools/sampen/
        [3] Madalena Costa, Ary Goldberger, CK Peng. Multiscale entropy analysis
            of biological signals
    """
    if tolerance is None:
        tolerance = 0.1 * np.std(time_series)

    n = len(time_series)
    prev = np.zeros(n)
    curr = np.zeros(n)
    A = np.zeros((sample_length))  # number of matches for m = [1,...,template_length - 1]
    B = np.zeros((sample_length))  # number of matches for m = [1,...,template_length]

    for i in range(n - 1):
        nj = n - i - 1
        ts1 = time_series[i]
        for jj in range(nj):
            j = jj + i + 1
            if abs(time_series[j] - ts1) < tolerance:  # distance between two vectors
                curr[jj] = prev[jj] + 1
                temp_ts_length = min(sample_length, curr[jj])
                for m in range(int(temp_ts_length)):
                    A[m] += 1
                    if j < n - 1:
                        B[m] += 1
            else:
                curr[jj] = 0
        for j in range(nj):
            prev[j] = curr[j]

    N = n * (n - 1) // 2

    B2=np.empty(sample_length)
    B2[0]=N
    B2[1:]=B[:sample_length - 1]
    similarity_ratio = A / B2
    se = - np.log(similarity_ratio)
    return se
```

**Timings**

```
a = np.random.rand(1, 95000)[0] #Python
a = rand(1, 95000) #Matlab
Python 3.6, Numba 0.40dev, Matlab 2016b, Core i5-3210M

Python:       487s
Python+Numba: 12.2s
Matlab:       71.1s
```