# Override matmul for special matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have an application where I have to do a lot of (costly) matrix multiplication. Many of these matrices, but not all, have special structure for which it is easy for me to define a custom data representation and a custom matrix multiplication routine. I want to be able to mix and match these with arbitrary matrices that are represented as ordinary 2d ndarrays.

To take the simplest possible example, I would like to do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

class IdentityMatrix:
    def __matmul__(self, other):
        return other

    def __rmatmul__(self, other):
        return other

    __array_priority__ = 10000
```

where an `IdentityMatrix` knows that it does nothing when acting upon a matrix on either the left or the right. My hope was that setting `__array_priority__` to a high number would cause this to always override an ndarray's matrix multiplication when the other argument is an ndarray, but this does not work:

```py
In [2]: A = IdentityMatrix
   ...: B = np.array([[3,4],[6,1]])
   ...: A @ B
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8f0beccd3079> in <module>()
      1 A = IdentityMatrix
      2 B = np.array([[3,4],[6,1]])
----> 3 A @ B

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 0 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
```

Reversing the inputs gives the same error. The frustrating thing is that this does [seem to work for operations other than matmul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252765/overriding-other-rmul-with-your-classs-mul).

Is there any simple way to override matmul in the way I'd like?

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis: `A = IdentityMatrix()`

Comment: Yikes, that does indeed explain it. :) Thanks so much!