# How to call `__rsub__` properly with a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Consider the following snippet:

```py
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        print(type(other), other)

obj = MyClass()
arr = np.ones(3)

arr - obj
```

I would expect it to print `<class 'numpy.ndarray'> [1. 1. 1.]`.
But in fact, it seems to call to `__rsub__` for every element:

```
<class 'float'> 1.0
<class 'float'> 1.0
<class 'float'> 1.0
```

**Is there any way to tell numpy I want the *first* behavior**, i.e. delegating the *entire* substraction to `MyClass`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On NumPy 1.13+, you can do this with NumPy-specific hooks, but you can't have your `__rsub__` beat `__sub__` methods in general.

---

`__rsub__` is tried if the left operand's `__sub__` can't handle the operation, but the left operand *can* handle this operation. A NumPy array's `__sub__` will accept any RHS and perform a broadcasted subtraction. Your object's `__rsub__` only comes into play for the individual operations in the broadcasted subtraction.

There is one very limited case where `__rsub__` is tried first, which is if the class of the RHS is a subclass of the class of the LHS. You could technically subclass `numpy.ndarray`, but that would come with a *lot* of extra baggage and still do nothing for `numpy.matrix([[1]]) - obj` or other subclasses.

There is no way to say "I want my `__rsub__` to win over everything". It doesn't exist, and it wouldn't make sense for it to exist, because what would happen if you tried to subtract two objects that both want to declare their method beats everything?

---

So that's the general case. Specifically for NumPy, though, you can hook into the mechanisms that `numpy.ndarray.__sub__` delegates to.

NumPy arrays delegate `__sub__` to the NumPy [ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) machinery. There are a bunch of weird customization options there, but we're interested in a specific use of one specific option: by setting [`__array_ufunc__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.class.__array_ufunc__) to `None` at class level, you can declare a class incompatible with ufuncs. This means that all NumPy operator overloads will return `NotImplemented`, letting your class handle the operation. This affects *all* operators and a bunch more stuff, but in a way that you probably want:

```
class MyClass:
    __array_ufunc__ = None
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        print(type(other), other)
```

If you want something more targeted than blocking all ufuncs, you can implement an actual `__array_ufunc__` method and just handle the case where the ufunc is subtraction and an instance of your class is the RHS:

```
class MyClass:
    def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs):
        if ufunc is not numpy.subtract:
            return NotImplemented
        if method != '__call__':
            return NotImplemented
        if len(inputs) != 2 or inputs[1] is not self:
            return NotImplemented
        if kwargs:
            return NotImplemented
        return self.__rsub__(inputs[0])
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        print(type(other), other)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes sense.

Comment: @lum: See expanded answer for a NumPy-specific workaround. You can't make your `__rsub__` beat `__sub__` methods in general, but you *can* tell the NumPy ufunc machinery not to handle instances of your class.

Comment: ah, that's really interesting! Thanks a lot for the pointer, I believe that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: how about `__array_priority__`?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/40252765/901925v

Comment: @hpaulj: That's part of an old system the devs want to remove, so I didn't want to suggest it. Also, there are issues with knowing what's a high enough value.