# How can I make operator overloading work correctly when adding a sibling class?

Tags: python, inheritance, operator-overloading, subclass

As an example, assume a codebase includes the following class. Instances represent complex numbers that can be multiplied:

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, re, im):
        self.re, self.im = re, im
    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if isinstance(rhs, Complex): return Complex(...)
        return NotImplemented

assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex
```

Real numbers are a special-case of complex numbers, so the codebase also includes a subclass for them:

```
class Real(Complex):
    def __init__(self, re):
        self.re, self.im = re, 0
    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if isinstance(rhs, Real): return Real(...)
        if isinstance(rhs, Complex): return Complex(...)
        return NotImplemented
    def __rmul__(rhs, lhs):
        if isinstance(lhs, Complex): return Complex(...)
        return NotImplemented

assert type(Real(0) * Real(0)) is Real
assert type(Real(0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex
assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Real(0)) is Complex
```

I believe the above is all idiomatic Python, and it all works fine. Now assume that I want to add a class for imaginary numbers to the existing code. `Imaginary` is a subclass of `Complex` and a sibling class of `Real`:

```
class Imaginary(Complex):
    def __init__(self, im):
        self.re, self.im = 0, im
    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if isinstance(rhs, Imaginary): return Real(...)
        if isinstance(rhs, Real): return Imaginary(...)
        if isinstance(rhs, Complex): return Complex(...)
        return NotImplemented
    def __rmul__(rhs, lhs):
        if isinstance(lhs, Real): return Imaginary(...)
        if isinstance(lhs, Complex): return Complex(...)
        return NotImplemented

assert type(Imaginary(0) * Imaginary(0)) is Real
assert type(Imaginary(0) * Real(0)) is Imaginary
assert type(Imaginary(0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex
assert type(Real(0) * Imaginary(0)) is Imaginary  # AssertionError
assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Imaginary(0)) is Complex
```

Unfortunately one of these assertions fails. `type(Real(0) * Imaginary(0))` is `Complex` rather than `Imaginary` because Python performs the multiplication by calling `Real.__mul__` instead of `Imaginary.__rmul__`.

Is there any way to write `Imaginary` so that the overloaded operators all work as expected, without modifying `Complex` or `Real`?

Or should `Complex` and `Real` be written differently to enable this to work (without requiring them to have knowledge of `Imaginary`)?

Comment: This sort of sounds like the [Circle-ellipse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle%E2%80%93ellipse_problem).

Comment: Sorry, it's going to call the LHS `__mul__` first... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181320/under-what-circumstances-are-rmul-called

Answer (score 2):

Dymtro is right that using `isinstance` can be substituted for a type/class check, however you should not check `obj.__class__` directly.  Instead, use `type(obj) is Classname` to do the check, just like you're doing with your Assert checks!  Here I'm substituting 0's for the actual complex math:

```python
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, re, im):
        self.re, self.im = re, im
    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if type(rhs) is Complex: return Complex(0,0)
        return NotImplemented

assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex

class Real(Complex):
    def __init__(self, re):
        self.re, self.im = re, 0
    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if type(rhs) is Real: return Real(0)
        if type(rhs) is Complex: return Complex(0,0)
        return NotImplemented
    def __rmul__(rhs, lhs):
        if type(lhs) is Complex: return Complex(0,0)
        return NotImplemented

assert type(Real(0) * Real(0)) is Real
assert type(Real(0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex
assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Real(0)) is Complex

class Imaginary(Complex):
    def __init__(self, im):
        self.re, self.im = 0, im
    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if type(rhs) is Imaginary: return Real(0)
        if type(rhs) is Real: return Imaginary(0)
        if type(rhs) is Complex: return Complex(0,0)
        return NotImplemented
    def __rmul__(rhs, lhs):
        if type(lhs) is Real: return Imaginary(0)
        if type(lhs) is Complex: return Complex(0,0)
        return NotImplemented

assert type(Imaginary(0) * Imaginary(0)) is Real
assert type(Imaginary(0) * Real(0)) is Imaginary
assert type(Imaginary(0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex
assert type(Real(0) * Imaginary(0)) is Imaginary  # (No longer) AssertionError
assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Imaginary(0)) is Complex
```

### Alternate Approach 1

Like I said in the comment above, Python will try to evaluate the `__mul__` of the LHS first with the arguments.  Only when that fails as NotImplemented will it attempt the `__rmul__` of the RHS.  See:  [Under what circumstances are __rmul__ called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181320/under-what-circumstances-are-rmul-called)

You can try to force the other way first without Real knowing *specifically* about Imaginary, but thinking there might be another object that should take precedence to Complex, like so:

```
class Real(Complex):
    def __init__(self, re):
        self.re, self.im = re, 0
    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if isinstance(rhs, Real): return Real(0)
        try:
            if hasattr(rhs,"__rmul__"):
                return rhs.__rmul__(lhs)
        except NotImplementedError:
            pass
        if isinstance(rhs, Complex): return Complex(0,0)
        return NotImplemented
    def __rmul__(rhs, lhs):
        if isinstance(lhs, Complex): return Complex(0,0)
        return NotImplemented
```

### Alternate Approach 2

If you make it the other way around, where Complex inherits from a combination of Real and Imaginary, you can build it progressively in the way that you've done, where the first class only knows of itself, the second class knows of itself and the first class, and finally the third class knows about everybody.

```
class Real:
    def __init__(self, re):
        self.re = re
    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if isinstance(rhs, Real): return Real(lhs.re*rhs.re)
        return NotImplemented

assert type(Real(0) * Real(0)) is Real

class Imaginary:
    def __init__(self, im):
        self.im = im
    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if isinstance(rhs, Imaginary): return Real(lhs.im * rhs.im * -1)
        if isinstance(rhs, Real): return Imaginary(lhs.im * rhs.re)
        return NotImplemented
    def __rmul__(rhs, lhs):
        if isinstance(lhs, Real): return Imaginary(lhs.re * rhs.im)
        return NotImplemented

class Complex(Real,Imaginary):
    def __init__(self, re, im):
        self.re, self.im = re, im
    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if isinstance(rhs, Real): return Complex(lhs.re * rhs.re,lhs.im * rhs.re)
        if isinstance(rhs, Imaginary): return Complex(-1*rhs.im * lhs.im,rhs.im * lhs.re)
        if isinstance(rhs, Complex): return Complex(lhs.re*rhs.re - lhs.im*rhs.im,lhs.re*rhs.im+rhs.re*lhs.im)
        return NotImplemented
    def __rmul__(rhs,lhs):
        if isinstance(lhs, Real): return Complex(lhs.re*rhs.re, lhs.re*rhs.im)
        if isinstance(lhs, Imaginary): return Complex(-1 * lhs.im*rhs.im, lhs.im*rhs.re)

assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex
assert type(Real(0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex
assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Real(0)) is Complex


assert type(Imaginary(0) * Imaginary(0)) is Real
assert type(Imaginary(0) * Real(0)) is Imaginary
assert type(Imaginary(0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex
assert type(Real(0) * Imaginary(0)) is Imaginary  # NOT an AssertionError
assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Imaginary(0)) is Complex
```

Answer (score 0):

### `isinstance` is the root of the problem

#### Definition

The problem appears as `isinstance` "Return whether an object is an instance of a class or of a subclass thereof."

```
>>> help(isinstance)

isinstance(obj, class_or_tuple, /)
    Return whether an object is an instance of a class or of a subclass thereof.
    
    A tuple, as in ``isinstance(x, (A, B, ...))``, may be given as the target to
    check against. This is equivalent to ``isinstance(x, A) or isinstance(x, B)
    or ...`` etc.
```

#### What does it mean?

```py
>>> class A:
    pass

>>> class B(A):
    pass

>>> b = B()

>>> isinstance(b, A)
True # `b` instance is an instance of the sublass A

>>> isinstance(b, B)
True # `b` instance is an instance of the class
```

#### Why `assert` is failed?

```py
class Real(Complex):
    def __init__(self, re):
        self.re, self.im = re, 0
    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if isinstance(rhs, Real): return Real(...)
        if isinstance(rhs, Complex): return Complex(...) 
        #                  ^^^^^^^
        # Complex is an instance of Complex
        # Real is an instance of Complex
        # Imagionary is an instance of Complex
        #
        # Any subclass of Complex will return True here.

        return NotImplemented
    def __rmul__(rhs, lhs):
        if isinstance(lhs, Complex): return Complex(...)
        return NotImplemented
```

### Solution

A solution here is to compare classes instead of `isinstance` So,

```py
if isinstance(rhs, Complex): return Complex(...)
```

becames

```py
if rhs.__class__ == Complex: return Complex(...)
```

Here the exact classes are compared, not the whole hierarchy.

Full code where all asserts are passed

```py
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, re, im):
        self.re, self.im = re, im

    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if rhs.__class__ == Complex: return Complex(1, 1)
        return NotImplemented


assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex


class Real(Complex):
    def __init__(self, re):
        super().__init__(re, 0)

    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if rhs.__class__ == Real: return Real(1)
        if rhs.__class__ == Complex: return Complex(1, 0)
        return NotImplemented

    def __rmul__(rhs, lhs):
        if lhs.__class__ == Complex: return Complex(1, 0)
        return NotImplemented


assert type(Real(0) * Real(0)) is Real
assert type(Real(0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex
assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Real(0)) is Complex


class Imaginary(Complex):
    def __init__(self, im):
        super().__init__(0, im)

    def __mul__(lhs, rhs):
        if rhs.__class__ == Imaginary: return Real(1)
        if rhs.__class__ == Real: return Imaginary(1)
        if rhs.__class__ == Complex: return Complex(1, 1)
        return NotImplemented

    def __rmul__(rhs, lhs):
        if lhs.__class__ == Real: return Imaginary(1)
        if lhs.__class__ == Complex: return Complex(1, 1)
        return NotImplemented


assert type(Imaginary(0) * Imaginary(0)) is Real
assert type(Imaginary(0) * Real(0)) is Imaginary
assert type(Imaginary(0) * Complex(0, 0)) is Complex
assert type(Real(0) * Imaginary(0)) is Imaginary
assert type(Complex(0, 0) * Imaginary(0)) is Complex
```